# ¿cómo obtener el nombre e ID del emoji de discord con comando?

Tags: python, discord.py

estoy intentando programar un mini bot que te muestre sólo el nombre e id del emoji a traves de un comando de discord, pero tengo un pequeño problema y esque el código que estoy usando sólo me muestra todos los emojis que estan actualmente en el servidor y sólo me gustaria que se muestre un sólo emoji nombre e id que selecione de la lista de emojis

Esto es lo que se me muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me gustaria qué solo aparezca uno sólo

Ejemplo:
!emoji + el icono del emoji del servidor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que estoy usando ahora mismo:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
 
 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="ayuda bot") #Comando
bot.remove_command("help") # Borra el comando por defecto !help
 
 
 
@bot.command()
async def emojis(ctx):
        for emoji in ctx.guild.emojis:
            await ctx.send(f"{emoji.name} {emoji.id}")
 

 
 
 
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("BOT listo!")
    
 
    
bot.run('') #OBTEN UN TOKEN EN: https://discord.com/developers/applications
```

Me podrian ayudar?, muchas gracias!

Comment: Claro que podríamos ayudarte. Si no quieres que responda con todos los emojis empieza por hacer que tu bucle no imprima todos los emojis! Es bien fácil la solución. En ningún momento estás leyendo el emoji que introdujo el usuario, que sería el primer paso para poder buscarlo en la lista de emojis. Empieza por eso, obtén el emoji escrito por el usuario, luego ya puedes recorrer la lista de emojis para buscarlo y cuando lo encuentres, puedes responder con lo que quieras, y ya está. Tu pregunta no tiene un error concreto, el código hace exactamente lo que le pides así que no podemos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
 
 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="ayuda bot") 
bot.remove_command("help")
 
 
 
@bot.command()
async def emoji(ctx, *, emojii):
        
            await ctx.send(f"\{emojii}")

 
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("BOT listo!")
    
 
    
bot.run('')
```

Espero que te sirva